# Problem from Discrete Mathematics and its application for Rosen section 4.4

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, conjectures

> **This exercise outlines a proof of Fermat’s little theorem.**
>
> **a)** Suppose that a is not divisible by the prime p. Show that no two of
> the integers 1 · a, 2 · a, . . . , (p − 1)a are congruent modulo p.
>
> **b)** Conclude from part (a) that the product of 1, 2, . . . , p − 1 is
> congruent modulo p to the product of a, 2a, . . . , (p − 1)a. Use this
> to show that (p − 1)! ≡ a p−1 (p − 1)! (mod p).

*I already  solved the first problem **(a)**   but I couldn't solve Problem **(b)**
So can any one please help me to solve it, **mean problem (b)** ?*

**Note** : I can't use Fermat’s little theorem  to prove it as this problem is to prove the Fermat’s little theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) The sets $\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ and $\{a,2a,\dots,(p-1)a\}$ are the same modulo $p$ by item (a). So the product of their elements must be equal: $(p-1)! \equiv a\cdot 2a \cdot {\dots} \cdot (p-1)a \equiv a^{p-1}(p-1)! \pmod p$.

Comment: But how you concluded that two sets are the same modulo p by item (a)

Comment: The set $A = \{a,2a,\dots,(p-1)a\}$ has $p-1$ elements modulo $p$, since no two of them are congruent. If $ja \equiv 0 \pmod p$ for some $1 \le j \le p-1$ then either $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $j \equiv 0 \pmod p$. In both cases we have a contradiction. Therefore $ja \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ for every $1 \le j \le p-1$. Hence $A$ contains $p-1$ non-congruent and non-zero numbers, which implies $A = \{1,2,\dots,p-1\} \pmod p$.

Answer (score 0):

a) Suppose there are two such: $a\cdot i$ and $a\cdot j$, then $p\mid a(i-j)$ so $p\mid i-j$ and thus $p\mid |i-j|$. But then $p\leq |i-j|$ since $i \ne j$. But also $|i-j|\leq p-1$. A contradiction.